# Azure Face API - JSON Parsing Error when disabling 'returnFaceId'

Tags: azure, http

I created a resource on Microsoft Azure Face with F0 tier, then wrote the code below:

```
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect"

HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': "[My Key]"
}

PARAMS = {
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'true',
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'detectionModel': 'detection_03',
}

url = "https://u.cubeupload.com/Johann/test1.jpg"

data = {'url': url}

r = requests.post(BASE_URL, data=data, headers=HEADERS, params=PARAMS)

print(r.json())
```

Although I expected it to return face information, it instead returned:

```
{'error': {'code': 'InvalidRequest', 'message': 'Invalid request has been sent.', 'innererror': {'code': 'UnsupportedFeature', 'message': 'Feature is not supported, missing approval for one or more of the following features: Identification,Verification. Please apply for access at https://aka.ms/facerecognition'}}}
```

Therefore, I set the `'returnFaceId'` attribute to `'false'`. But then I was shown

```
{'error': {'code': 'BadArgument', 'message': 'JSON parsing error.'}}
```

I would like to know where my mistake is and how should I correct it. Here is some other information about my resource.

Status: Active

Region: East US

API Type: Face

Pricing Tier: F0 (Free)

My Access: Owner

Limited Access Approval: None

Answer (score 0):

- Here i have a work around where instead of using rest Api you can use [faceSDK](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-face/) to detect the faces.
- you have to create your face client and then use the `detect_with_url`  function to detect the faces.
- Here I have created a console app which will print the result after detection.

```
from  azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face  import  FaceClient

from  msrest.authentication  import  CognitiveServicesCredentials

endpoint = ""
key = "" 
image_url = "" 

face_client = FaceClient(endpoint, CognitiveServicesCredentials(key))

detected_faces = face_client.face.detect_with_url(url=image_url, detection_model='detection_03' ,return_face_landmarks = True , returnFaceId = True )

print(detected_faces)
```

- My endpoint is also in EASTUS and FO price tier

output:

[image]

Comment: Exact same code, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johann/Desktop/crowd-management/main_msface_old.py", line 19, in <module>
    faces = face_client.face.detect_with_url(url=test_image,
  File "/Users/johann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/vision/face/operations/_face_operations.py", line 547, in detect_with_url
    raise models.APIErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models._models_py3.APIErrorException: (InvalidRequest) Invalid request has been sent.

Comment: can you check validity your endpoint and key ? as they are the only variables and make sure you are using the latest version of face SDK